# Why does ScanF take two inputs from string

Tags: c

The first ScanF takes both inputs when I type a character and an integer is expected.

see image below:[image]

As you can see when I type "55ape" for ScanNum_A it sets ScanNum_B = 0.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Also consider that `scanf` is a poor choice for interactive input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because 
`ape` is still left in the input stream and your second `scanf` tries to read it but fails as it was expecting `integer` but found `chars`.

You can clear the input buffer after your first `scanf` as below.

```
//first scanf

int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }


//second scanf
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, so I have to clear the buffer before each ScanF.

Comment: @MetalMike Yes! also include the suggestion from AndrewHenle in comment section.